# Error: E/flutter ( 8247): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am getting this error whenever I run my `Flutter` app:

**E/flutter ( 8247): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.**

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


  List responseJson;
  List EventDetails ;

  Future<String> fetchPost() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        "https://....",
        headers: {
          HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION:
          "Bearer .."
              });

    for(var i = 0; i< (responseJson?.length ?? 0);i++) {
      print(responseJson[i]["id"]);


      final eventDetailsRepsonse = await http.get(
          "https:..." + responseJson[i]["id"].toString(),
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION:
            "Bearer .."
});

        EventDetails.add(json.decode(eventDetailsRepsonse.body));

      EventDetails = responseJson;
    }

    //print(response.body);
this.setState(() {
  responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print(response.body);
  print(responseJson);

});
//    data = JSON.decode(response.body);
    print(responseJson[1]["code"]);
    print(responseJson[1]["event_banner"]);

    //return new Post.fromJson(responseJson);

  }
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What is the code at `package:loginapp/myevents.dart:54:35`. That looks like a problem in your code. We need to see the code to be able to diagnose.

Comment: I have edited the text above, please have a look at it, thank you!

Comment: Your list is not initialized ?

Comment: What line causes this error? Try `List EventDetails = [];` instead of `List EventDetails ;`

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems to work now!

Answer (score 1):

`responseJson` is not yet initialized when

```
for(var i = 0; i<responseJson.length;i++) {
```

is executed.

Changing it to

```
for(var i = 0; i< (responseJson?.length ?? 0);i++) {
```

might fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, however now I am getting:

The method 'add' was called on null.

Comment: I would need more details. That seems to be a different problem.

Comment: Sure. I have updated the box above, thank you very much for your time so far.

Comment: If this solves your problem please consider accepting the answer with the checkmark below the up/downvote buttons.

Comment: Hi  Günter,
For some reason I still get:
[ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 6323): RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1

Comment: What line? You get this information in case of an error, I need this info.If it's `responseJson[i]` I don't have a way to infer why `responseJson` might be empty.

Comment: Apparently EventDetails is empty as I have tried to print it out and it gives me [ ] .